# Convert Byte[] to Image to show in datagrid column

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

[image]I'm trying to put a picture in a datagrid column, the picture is in Byte[] type and i need to convert it to show it in the datagrid

```xml
<controls:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Foto" Tag="Foto" >
                    <controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <Image Source="{Binding Foto, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource ByteArrayToImage}}" ></Image>
                                <Button Click="Foto_Button_Click">Click me</Button>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I think i can do that with the Converter property, but i don't know how to implement or where to implement it.
Thanks for the help.

I tried using this code but i get this exception, "The component wasn't found" do you have any idea what it might be?

Comment: Can you add your ViewModel and a copy of what you have done with your ValueConverter already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
stream.Seek(0);
```

This line before

```
await image.SetSourceAsync(stream);
```

solved the exception problem

Answer (score 1):

Converting a byte array to a `BitmapImage` involves asynchronous operations.

Generally, we recommend that [IValueConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.binding.converter) be considered when there is only a synchronous method. When it comes to asynchronous, you can consider creating a [UserControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.usercontrol) to write a component and perform asynchronous conversion inside the component (like use [DependencyProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/dependency-properties-overview)).

**TestControl.xaml**

```xml
<Grid>
    <Image x:Name="TestImage" ></Image>
</Grid>
```

**TestControl.xaml.cs**

```cs
public sealed partial class TestControl : UserControl
{
    public TestControl()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    public byte[] ImageSource
    {
        get { return (byte[])GetValue(ImageSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ImageSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ImageSource", typeof(byte[]), typeof(TestControl), new PropertyMetadata(null,new PropertyChangedCallback(Source_Changed)));

    private static async void Source_Changed(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.NewValue!=null && e.NewValue is byte[] data)
        {
            var instance = d as TestControl;
            BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
            using (InMemoryRandomAccessStream stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream())
            {
                await stream.WriteAsync(data.AsBuffer());
                await image.SetSourceAsync(stream);
            }
            instance.TestImage.Source = image;
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```xml
<DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel>
        <TestControl Source="{Binding Foto, Mode=TwoWay}"></TestControl>
        <Button Click="Foto_Button_Click">Click me</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Best regards.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment, can you please explain what the code does and how it is used? Thanks again

Comment: also when do you consider using asynchronous methods instead of synchronous? thanks

Comment: The byte array cannot be used directly as the source of the `Image` control, so it needs to be converted, and the more suitable conversion target is `BitmapImage`. In order for the UI thread to remain responsive, we need to choose an asynchronous method. But for `Converter`, once we use asynchronous, it will return a `Task<object>`, which is not conducive to the parsing of Image, so we can create a `UserControl` to operate

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation, i tried using your example, and a made a UserControl page to convert the image, but i'm getting an exception, and i don't understand why or how to fix it, can you give me a hand? i updated the post with a picture of the exception, thanks a lot

Comment: Hi, I tested a few pictures but did not reproduce the problem. Do you see this error in all your pictures, or confined to one? Is it possible to provide a minimum runnable demo so that we can reproduce your problem

Answer (score 1):

I don't think IValueConverters are meant to do things async. You should add a property to the class you are bound to for getting the image instead of using the IValueConverter.

```
 public BitmapImage Image
            {
                get { return _image; }
                set
                {
                    _image = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged();
                }
            }
     public byte[] Thumbprint
            {
                get { return _thumbprint; }
                set
                {
                    _thumbprint = value;
                    if (value != null)
                    {
                        ConvertToBitMapImageAsync(value);
                    }
                    RaisePropertyChanged();
                }
            }


 public async Task<BitmapImage> ConvertToBitMapImageAsync(byte[] bytes)
        {
            if (bytes != null)
            {
                Image = new BitmapImage();
                var stream = bytes?.AsBuffer()?.AsStream()?.AsRandomAccessStream();
                await Image.SetSourceAsync(stream);
                return Image;
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, can you please explain how that works? i'm a begginer with UWP, i didn't understand what was Thumbprint

Comment: Thumbprint is a byte array type property, that will hold your byte or stream, when this going to set a new value. By using ConvertToBitMapImageAsync method it will update you bitmapImage Property.